# Slected autocomplete number and change data-table data in Vuetify and Vue.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

My goal is selecting the number in autocomplete and data-table going to change to selecting number.

Autocomplete works but if I choose some number of autocomplete, others disappear. I want to keep displayed all number in autocomplete form and can select other number or all numbers.

I don't have any ideas to make Typescript code.

```
    <template>
      <v-app>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="6">
            <v-autocomplete
              v-model="workerInfo"
              dense
              :items="test_items"
              item-text="number_id"
              item-value="number_id"
              @change="worker_select()"
            ></v-autocomplete>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="8">
            <v-data-table dense :headers="headers" :items="test_items" class="elevation-1"></v-data-table>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-app>
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
    
    @Component
    export default class AutoCompleteTest extends Vue {
      workerInfo: string = ''
      headers = [
        { text: 'name', value: 'name' },
        { text: 'id', value: 'number_id' }
      ]
    
      test_items = [
        { name: 'jon', number_id: '1' },
        { name: 'bob', number_id: '2' },
        { name: 'jack', number_id: '3' },
        { name: 'jen', number_id: '4' },
        { name: 'sam', number_id: '5' }
      ]
    
      worker_select(item: any) {
        let selectArr = this.test_items
        if (this.workerInfo != '') {
          selectArr = selectArr.filter((item: any) => {
            const number_id: string = item['number_id']
            return number_id.includes(this.workerInfo)
          })
          this.test_items = selectArr
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Mr.pai.not.pi)  Thak you for your editing. I realized my English has many problems. I really appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add any reproducible code! Looks like once you select from autocomplete you are updating data-table that will be working fine(can improve `number_id.includes(this.workerInfo)` )!